# how to connect output signal of one module to input signal of other module

Tags: vhdl

Suppose my VHDL code is like this:

```
entity x1:
port(a: out std_logic;
....
....
);
architecture behv1 of x1 is
....
end behv1;

entity y1 
port(b: in std_logic;
....
....
);
architecture behv1 of y1 is
begin
m1: x1 port map(a=>b);    
end behv1;
```

So, here a is the output signal of entity x1 which is connected directly to input b of other entity y1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're kinda going about it in the wrong way.

`entity y1` provides the *interface* of the `y1` entity. It specifies that you have an input to the entity, `b`. This means that you can read the value of `b` from inside your `architecture` declaration. You should then implement what you want your `y1` module to do inside `architecture behav1`.

From what I understand though, you want to instantiate an `x1` and a `y1`, then connect them together. To do this, you need to provide an implementation of `x1` and `y1`, and then instantiate both in a separate top-level and connect them together. Something like this:

```
entity x1:
port(a: out std_logic;
....
....
);
architecture behv1 of x1 is
    -- Do something...
end behv1;

entity y1 
port(b: in std_logic;
....
....
);
architecture behv1 of y1 is
begin
    -- Do something...    
end behv1;

entity toplevel
port (
    clk : in std_logic;
    ...
);
architecture toplevel_arch of toplevel is
    signal x1_output : std_logic; -- Temp to connect both modules
begin
    m_x1: x1 port map(a => x1_output);
    m_y1: y1 port map(b => x1_output);
end toplevel_arch;
```

Answer (score 2):

The following example analyzes, elaborates and simulates.

It illustrates how to connect inputs and outputs hierarchically.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity x3 is
    port (
        x3in:   in  std_logic;
        x3out:  out std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture behv3 of x3 is
begin
    x3out <= x3in;
end architecture;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity y3 is
    port (
        y3in:   in  std_logic;
        y3out:  out std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture behv3 of y3 is
begin   
    y3out <= y3in;
end architecture;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity z3 is
    port (
        z3in:   in  std_logic;
        z3out:  out std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture foo of z3 is

    component x3 is
        port (
            x3in:   in  std_logic;
            x3out:  out std_logic
        );
    end component;

    component y3 is
        port (
            y3in:   in  std_logic;
            y3out:  out std_logic
        );
    end component;

    signal x3out:   std_logic;

begin
u0:
    x3 
        port map ( 
            x3in => z3in,
            x3out => x3out
        );
u1:
    y3 
        port map ( 
            y3in => x3out,
            y3out => z3out
        );
end architecture;
```

The applicable rules can be found in the Language Reference Manual (LRM), IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.5.6.3 Port clauses:

> After a given description is completely elaborated (see Clause 14), if a formal port is associated with an actual that is itself a port, then the following restrictions apply depending upon the mode (see 6.5.2), if any, of the formal port:
>
> > a) For a formal port of mode **in**, the associated actual shall be a port of mode **in**, **out**, **inout**, or **buffer**. This restriction applies both to an actual that is associated as a name in the actual part of an association element and to an actual that is associated as part of an expression in the actual part of an association element.
> >     b) For a formal port of mode **out**, the associated actual shall be a port of mode **out**, **inout**, or **buffer**.
> >     c) For a formal port of mode **inout**, the associated actual shall be a port of mode **out**, **inout**, or **buffer**.
> >     d) For a formal port of mode **buffer**, the associated actual shall be a port of mode **out**, **inout**, or **buffer**.
> >     e) For a formal port of mode **linkage**, the associated actual may be a port of any mode.